# fb graph api multiple userid and page like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

from my ios app after fb login, facebook returns me the userid.

```
i call https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/likes/[pageid]?access_token=...
```

to check if the user likes my fb page. But i get empty array while the same user has liked my page from the web.

The user has different userId when logins directly to facebook website and different when logins in my app. While the user has liked my page from web , how can i see it in the api call from my app using the userid that fb returns me when he logins from my app?

Thank you very much

Comment: why do you want to know if the user liked your page? the question is important for the answer. bzw. you may want to read about app scoped ids.

Comment: i need to know because if he does he gets some more privilleges, thanks!

Comment: alright, then the answer is very clear: you are not allowed to do that, and it´s not possible (because you would not get the required user_likes permission approved for that). you should read the platform policy...actually, you MUST read it before using the graph api.

Comment: you are not allowed to reward users for liking a page, or gate content behind a page like.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there is no direct way of checking whether a particular user has liked a certain page or not using FB Graph API.

But i believe there is a workaround for this and you can try to hit the below URL in your browser

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/<page_id>/likers?ref=about
```

It will return all the people information who have liked the page provided. I am not sure would this return all the results or just some of them. But i believe you can try this.

You can then do some web scraping which will help you indentify whether 'person A' has liked a page say 'abc'.

Now you can hit the below endpoint to retreive all the likes this 'person a' has liked

```
FB.api('/person_id_obtained_from_above/likes')
```

But please note that you need **user_likes** permission to retrieve someone else's likes

Let me know if this worked for you.